# Applying background to HTML form not working

Tags: html, css, forms

This is part of my HTML form:

```
<form style="background: red; display: inline-block;" method="POST" action="index.php">
```

The `display: inline-block` style is being applied correctly, but `background: red` isn't.

Why is this?

Comment: What's not working? http://jsfiddle.net/QS5ff/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an inner div:

```
<form style="padding:0;" method="POST" action="index.php">
  <div style="display: inline-block; background-color: red;">
    <!-- Stuff here -->
  </div>
</form>
```

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/2zp87/)

Also, what browser are you using?

Comment: @AliAlzahrani No worries, happy to help any time.

Answer (score 1):

`background:red;` should be `background-color:red;`